# Spring Security login-processing-url issue

Tags: spring-security

When an exception is thrown during login which cannot be caught, the web page is getting blank with login-processsing-url shown in the address bar.

In my case I can never catch/handle the exception(using any of the handler refs like auth failure, auth success).

Can someone tell me how to handle this scenario?

Comment: What's the stack trace you see in the logs?

Comment: There is an exception from our backend DB team which cannot be caught/handled at our end.

Comment: Ok, paste that entire stack trace here.